# Is there any major changes from Postgres version 11 to postgres version 12?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

We wanted to upgrade postgres with version 12, wanted to know if we have any changes syntactical which will affect the queries written on postgres version 11.

I am currently checking using - but didn't find any difference which will change the queries.

https://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Pls. move the question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6):

[Appendix E. Release Notes - E.4.2. Migration to Version 12](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12.html#id-1.11.6.8.4) has notes about possible upgrade issues.

- Remove the special behavior of oid columns
- Remove data types abstime, reltime, and tinterval
- Remove the timetravel extension
- Move recovery.conf settings into postgresql.conf
- Do not allow multiple conflicting recovery_target* specifications
- Change SQL-style substring() to have standard-compliant greediness behavior
- Rename command-line tool pg_verify_checksums to pg_checksums
- In new btree indexes, the maximum index entry length is reduced by eight bytes, to improve handling of duplicate entries

And so on.

Comment: Hey @Schwern Thanks..But which one will affect my queries?

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre I can't tell you that, I don't know what your queries are. You'll have to determine that for yourself and rely on your tests to verify everything works.